# Moving files and folder structure based on days from one drive to another using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have requirement as below.

Source : `C:\s`

Destination: `C:\d`

files located are more than 255 characters.

Moving files based on last modified or written days(10) and it should copy complete folder structure, if any of the files not modified as per the last modified date it should be available at the source file in the same folder. While the other is modified, it should be created with a new directory with the same folder structure and file to moved in the same location as per the source location path.

I have tried PowerShell script using days, however the files are being copied into and folders are staying at the source itself.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\s -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-date).AddDays(0)} | Move-Item -destination C:\d
```

So far the output is giving only files but not the folder structure, if it is empty folder it should be moved to the destination folder.

Thanks 
Suman

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are getting all the files with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and filtering them, but when those files are piped to `Move-Item -Destination` you essentially are saying to take all files (regardless of the source) and put them into the single folder `C:\d`. If you want to preserve the directory structure, you have to pass through and specify the directory structure in the `Move-Item -Destination` parameter.

@AdminOfThings is correct, an easier way to do the move is to use [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Experimenting with the various switches should get you what you need. e.g.:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\s C:\d /move /e /minage:10
```

Where:

- `/move` says to move instead of copy
- `/e` is copy directories including empty ones
- `/minage:10` is to move files older than 10 days.

Comment: Robocopy main advantage to move the files with the security permission.

Comment: C:\s\MANUAL_DRIVER\DEUTSCH\02-01-1980\02-01-1980\02-01-1980\02-01-1980 the above robo copy moves and creates with date /month / year folders ,need to have same folder structure as source file having and the same should be present at the destination. if the subfolders having multiple files with different date stamp then it should pickup that particular files as per the min age 10 by creating the same directory structure.